# use external font in eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible set up Eclipse IDE to use external fonts from ttf files?

for example I want to make it use the fonts from Jetbrains,

I cannot figure out a way to do this,
I am working on linux,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install the font on your system (right click > install or something like that). Then, in Window > Preference > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts, you can select the font you want to change. If you want to change the coding font, select Text Font in 'Basic' and click 'edit', then choose the font you just install.

Comment: this is solution for windows, 
but for Liux, I am using Centos, I am not sure how to make installed fonts or system fonts visible for eclipse, not sure how eclipse handles system fonts, or where the fonts used in eclipse are located ...